# Error in cor(x, y, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")):unused argument (method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))

Tags: r

I am trying to use the correlation coefficient function, which I have done many times before without any problems.

```
  df <- read.csv(file = 'all_data.csv',header=T)
  pf <- read.csv(file = 'distances_20topics.csv',header=T)
  df<-na.omit(df)
  pf<-na.omit(pf)
  library("ggpubr")

  x<-df$Distance
  y<-df$Rating


  cor(x, y, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

Now, I am getting an error I never had before

```
 Error in cor(x, y, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")) : 
     unused argument (method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only use one method and not all in one command, try a single method it should work

```
cor(x,y,method="pearson")
```